# Connecting to web services using Rails (HTTP requests)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3, connection

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to implement APIs to retrieve account information from a web service. That is, I would like to connect to a web service that has the Account class and get information from the `show` action routed at the URI `http://<site_name>/accounts/1`.

At this time, in the web service `accounts_controller.rb` file I have:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render :json => @account.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Now I need some advice for connecting to the web service. In the client application, I should have a HTTP GET request, but here is my question: What is "the best" approach to connect to a web service making HTTP requests?

This code in the client application works:

```
url = URI.parse('http://<site_name>/accounts/1.json')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

@output = JSON(res.body)["account"]
```

but, is the above code "the way" to implement APIs?

Is it advisable to use third-party plugins and gems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since you're using [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) routes, they are your basic API. You're also returning structured JSON data easily consumable by an application.

There are other ways to implement a web services API (e.g. [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)), but this is a good and proper way.

Since it's a web services API, connecting to the correct URL and parsing the response is the way to go on the client side. Though if you need to access many different resources it might be a good idea to create a flexible way of building the request URL.

Comment: Is it good to use the 'net/http' (require 'net/http') or it should be advisable to use third-party plugins and gems?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to, I'm not sure of what libraries one would use instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need low-level tweak-ability offered by Net::HTTP, instead take a look at using [Open-URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/open-uri/1.9.2/frames), which comes with Ruby. It makes it easy to request a page and receive the body back. Open-URI doesn't have all the bells and whistles but for a lot of what I do it's plenty good.

A simple use looks like:

```
require 'open-uri'
body = open('http://www.example.com').read
```

The docs have many other examples.

These are other HTTP clients I like:

- [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient)
- [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus)

They are more tweakable and can handle multiple connections at once if that's what you need. For instance, Typhoeus has a suite of simplified calls, similar to Open-URI's. From the docs:

```
response = Typhoeus::Request.get("http://www.pauldix.net")
response = Typhoeus::Request.head("http://www.pauldix.net")
response = Typhoeus::Request.put("http://localhost:3000/posts/1", :body => "whoo, a body")
response = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://localhost:3000/posts", :params => {:title => "test post", :content => "this is my test"})
response = Typhoeus::Request.delete("http://localhost:3000/posts/1")
```

HTTPClient has similar shortened methods too.

Comment: open-uri is the way to go for the simple requests. If you need to post etc, take a look at rest-open-uri.

Comment: Can I handle multiple connections using Net::HTTP?

Comment: You can, but you'll do a lot more work setting up the threads. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html. I'd recommend looking at the Net::HTTP docs to see, then read both HTTPClient and Typhoeus + Hydra and decide. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579712/is-it-possible-to-initiate-multiple-parallel-http-requests-using-eventmachine-wit/4579840#4579840 is an example of Typhoeus + Hydra. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832956/best-way-to-concurrently-check-urls-for-status-i-e-200-301-404-for-multiple-ur/4833811#4833811 is another.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Rails' [ActiveResource](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) for most cases. Failing that, [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

Answer (score 1):

I would use ActiveResource if you just need a simple way to pull in rest-based resources. It's already included in rails and pretty trivial to set up. You just specify a base url and resource name in your ActiveResource subclass and then you can CRUD rest-based resources with an interface similar to that of ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

[**rest-client**](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) is the most popular gem for easily connecting to RESTful web services

Comment: It's popular. "Most popular"? I'd need to see proof.

Comment: That doesn't prove it's the most used, only downloaded a lot. Unless each client "phones home" to an impartial metric-gathering site, or sends unique identification that can be gathered from HTTPd logs, there's no usage metrics, and I know they don't do that. Saying its popular because it's downloaded a lot isn't overly useful; It could be downloaded a lot because they make a incremental updates forcing a lot of `gem update` requests. Numbers, without disclosure of the underlying metrics mean very little. Connections per client library would be a better measure.

Comment: @theTinMan - So you'd rather use imaginary usage metrics instead of real world download metrics? Good luck with that ;).
(And FYI, regarding incremental updates, it actually has *fewer* releases than the next two most downloaded clients.)

Comment: Figure out how to include real metrics for OpenURI and it'd be accurate. OpenURI is probably the most used of them all; It's convenient, easy to use and build-upon and built-in.

Comment: @theTinMan - OpenURI only supports GET requests, so it doesn't qualify as a REST client. (There's a project called rest-open-uri, but it's not as popular)

Comment: Since the OP is asking about GET requests, it should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the best solutions out there is the [Her gem](http://her-rb.org). It encapsulates restful requests providing objects with active-record like behavior.